# Sound not working in ICS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am using Media player to play a sound file. It is working well on 2.2 and 2.3 but not working for ICS 4.0.3, I have checked that mobile is not on silent mode. my code is:

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private void playSound(int soundType) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        });
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sound in ICS is played like this :
(i copied it from a previous post, so if theres any weird stuff in there i apologize)

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int mSoundID = mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
float lActualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float lMaxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float lVolume = lActualVolume / lMaxVolume;
// Is the sound loaded already?
if (mSoundIsLoaded) {
     mSoundPool.play(mSoundID, lVolume, lVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
}
```

You will have to put the sound file in your assets/raw directory.

edit: I forgot to mention where the mSoundIsLoaded parameter came from. I set it when my sound has been loaded. I do this in my onCreate method. when the sound is loaded I set the boolean field called mSoundIsLoaded. I do this to prevent NullPointerExceptions when playing the sound the loading of the sound looks like this:

```
mSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
         mSoundIsLoaded = true;
    }
});
mSoundID = mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
```

Comment: hi Wottah I try your mention code again it working fine for 2.2 but still not working for ICS . . .don't know what's issue .in my above code control goes inside mediaPlayer.start(); condition but this not giving any sound.more Suggestion Please ?

Comment: what device are you testing on?

Comment: its HTC One V with Android 4.0.3 OS .

Comment: hmm, I'm at a loss as to what is going wrong. doesn't  your logcat give you any warnings or messages?

Comment: Hello Wottah I see in logcat its not giving any exception or other message.I also debug the code but nothing showing . .

Comment: I really have no clue as to why your sound isn't playing. other sounds are playing properly on the device i presume?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i use in my app.. It is working fine in ICS

public void playWelcomeAudio() {

```
    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.welcome); 


                try {
                    if(afd!=null)
                    {
                        UtilLog.d(TAG, "INIT MEDIA PLAYER");
                        welcomeAudio = new MediaPlayer();
                        welcomeAudio.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
                        welcomeAudio.prepare();
                        welcomeAudio.start();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    UtilLog.e(TAG, "Audio error", e);
                }

        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

You can remove the thread. It is not necessory.